# writing strings inside head-element in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working with a site using client-side templates through knockout.js.

The backend api, and login, is written in rails.

What I want to do is have each client-side html template in a separate file, and then have those templates lifted into the page using the templates. Similar to how javascript files are lifted in.

So I have a directory in my app/assets called templates
Each template in the directory should be added to the page in a script tag with the type="text/html"

I've gotten so far as to product the actual templates content now I just want to put it in the html.erb file in the head property.
However it always lands in the Body as normal text, not as HTML.

I've defined the following method in my controller:

```
  def html_templates
    output = ''
    templates = Dir.glob 'app/assets/templates/*'
    templates.each { |template| 
      file = File.open(template, "rb")
      output += '<script type="text/html" id="'+(File.basename template, '.html')+'">'
      output += file.read
      output += '</script>'

    }
    return output

  end
```

I try to add it to the .erb layout file like so:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <%= html_templates %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Yet the output is always put in the body, with all my html escaped.

Also, if anyone has better solutions to have to solve this. Please, recommend.

Comment: try this: <%= raw html_templates %>

Comment: That did it! if you want to add it as an answer feel free :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks :) so basically you should use `raw` method whenever you don't want output to be escaped